# Routing resource does not handle "new" as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing, rails-routing

I have a simple rails application in which I'm trying to add a very simple type of record ("client_types") to a database.

I have a route in `routes.rb` which reads:

> `resources :client_types`

And as I understand it, should be a proxy to all of the conventional routes for my `client_types` resource.

So when I browse to the following URL `http://localhost:3000/client_types/new`, I get the following routing error at runtime:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"client_types"}`

Notice the action in question here is show, not new (and I have a method for both of these in my controller).

So... I added the following route below the resources route above, and viola, it works:

`match 'client_types/new' => 'client_types#new', :as => :client_type`

So what am I missing? My assumption was that `resources :client_types` in my routing file would have added a route matching the one I explicitly added later.

`rake routes` reveals the following:

```
client_types     GET    /client_types(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"client_types"}
                 POST   /client_types(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"client_types"}
new_client_type  GET    /client_types/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"client_types"}
edit_client_type GET    /client_types/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"client_types"}
client_type      GET    /client_types/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"client_types"}
                 PUT    /client_types/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"client_types"}
                 DELETE /client_types/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"client_types"}
 client_type            /client_types/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"client_types", :action=>"new"}
```

Comment: Please do `rake routes` and report what you see

Comment: "when I land" - Please describe how you "land" e.g. by url or from a link?

Comment: By "when I land" i mean on the url in the browser.

Comment: Please post your routes.rb file contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working. I had an issue in one of my views and this error message was a red herring.